# How to make specific color darken or lighten based on value in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, system.windows.media

I am developing wpf application. I am having the instance of Color object in C#. Suppose I have instance of red Color object i.e. `Color c = Color.FromArgb(255,255,0,0)` Now suppose that I have one value which ranges from 1 to 10. So based on this value I want to change the color of the 'c' object. I want light red for 1 and dark red for 10. The light red becomes the dark as the value increases from 1. How can I do this in C# for wpf application ? Can you please provide me any code or link through which I can resolve the above issue ?

Answer (score 12):

You can try to simply multiply red, green and blue components by some coefficient.

```
public static Color ChangeLightness(this Color color, float coef)
{
    return Color.FromArgb((int)(color.R * coef), (int)(color.G * coef),
        (int)(color.B * coef));
}
```

Or, if you'd like to use an integer value from 1 to 10 instead of the coefficient:

```
private const int MinLightness = 1;
private const int MaxLightness = 10;
private const float MinLightnessCoef = 1f;
private const float MaxLightnessCoef = 0.4f;

public static Color ChangeLightness(this Color color, int lightness)
{
    if (lightness < MinLightness)
        lightness = MinLightness;
    else if (lightness > MaxLightness)
        lightness = MaxLightness;

    float coef = MinLightnessCoef +
      (
        (lightness - MinLightness) *
          ((MaxLightnessCoef - MinLightnessCoef) / (MaxLightness - MinLightness))
      );

    return Color.FromArgb(color.A, (int)(color.R * coef), (int)(color.G * coef),
        (int)(color.B * coef));
}
```

Comment: which coefficient ? What should I pass as coef ?

Comment: coef is a value from 0 to 1; more is lighter, less is darker;

Comment: @NikolayKhil I'm trying this code but it gives this error "No overload for method 'FromArgb' takes 3 arguments" as the Alpha channel is not passed. Could you please advise

Comment: The first entry is not correct, one should use "FromRgb" - and, furthermore, the values need to get casted to byte.

Comment: Argh - ok, my fault. In fact, there are two different "Color" - Classes in .NET. The one Nikolay refers to is in System.Drawing, the one I'm referring to is in System.Windows.Media - oh, Microsoft... And yeah, if you take the class from the System.Drawing-Namespace, everything fits.

Comment: Is there some way in which you could make this function work in XAML?

Comment: If you are using Windows.Media then use `Color.FromArgb(color.Value.A, (byte)(color.Value.R * percent), (byte)(color.Value.G * percent), (byte)(color.Value.B * percent))`

Answer (score 2):

What about a Style DataTrigger, if you have a set number of values?

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=c%23+wpf+style+datatrigger

```
<Button>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NameOfYourProperty}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                            Value="#FF000000" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NameOfYourProperty}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                            Value="#FF110000" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NameOfYourProperty}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                            Value="#FF220000" />
                </DataTrigger>
                ( etc ... )
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Then if you need to reuse the style then you could put in the `<Resources>` section of your window/usercontrol.

Comment: I think you should read [the following thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot I could add comments now - should've posted it as one. I improved this answer though

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner solution would be to juxtapose 2 rectangles: one is the color you want, the other is black.

Then play with `Opacity` on the black rectangle to darken/lighten the underlying color.

It would look like:

```
<Grid>
   <Rectangle Fill="{Binding myColor}" />
   <Rectangle Fill="Black" Opacity="{Binding colorModifierPercentage}" />
</Grid>
```

Of course, `colorModifierPercentage` must be a number between 0 and 1, and rectangle can be any [Shape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you're using a slider with a minimum value of `1` and a maximum value of `10`. You can just multiply the value by `25.5 (255 / max value)`. Then, subtract that answer from max value (255) and use that as the red value.

```
double newRedValue = 255 - (slider.Value * (255 / slider.Maximum));
int redValue = Convert.ToInt32(newRedValue);
Color c = Color.FromArgb(redValue ,255,0,0)
```

You can replace `255 / slider.Maximum` with a constant value since it will likely remain the same. The formula above will create an inverse effect, so the lower the slider value, the brighter the shade of red. Of course, a value of 10 will result in `red` being `0`, so you can add a minimum there value if you don't want the red component to be that low.

Answer (score 1):

There is [an article about it at CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49650/WPF-Color-Conversions):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a WPF RGB color to an HSL color
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rgbColor">The RGB color to convert.</param>
    /// <returns>An HSL color object equivalent to the RGB color object passed in.</returns>
    static HlsColor RgbToHls(Color rgbColor)
    {
        // Initialize result
        var hlsColor = new HlsColor();

        // Convert RGB values to percentages
        double r = (double)rgbColor.R / 255;
        var g = (double)rgbColor.G / 255;
        var b = (double)rgbColor.B / 255;
        var a = (double)rgbColor.A / 255;

        // Find min and max RGB values
        var min = Math.Min(r, Math.Min(g, b));
        var max = Math.Max(r, Math.Max(g, b));
        var delta = max - min;

        /* If max and min are equal, that means we are dealing with 
         * a shade of gray. So we set H and S to zero, and L to either
         * max or min (it doesn't matter which), and  then we exit. */

        //Special case: Gray
        if (max == min)
        {
            hlsColor.H = 0;
            hlsColor.S = 0;
            hlsColor.L = max;
            return hlsColor;
        }

        /* If we get to this point, we know we don't have a shade of gray. */

        // Set L
        hlsColor.L = (min + max) / 2;

        // Set S
        if(hlsColor.L < 0.5)
        {
            hlsColor.S = delta / (max + min);
        }
        else
        {
            hlsColor.S = delta / (2.0 - max - min);
        }

        // Set H
        if (r == max) hlsColor.H = (g - b) / delta;
        if (g == max) hlsColor.H = 2.0 + (b - r) / delta;
        if (b == max) hlsColor.H = 4.0 + (r - g) / delta;
        hlsColor.H *= 60;
        if (hlsColor.H < 0) hlsColor.H += 360;

        // Set A
        hlsColor.A = a;

        // Set return value
        return hlsColor;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a WPF HSL color to an RGB color
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hlsColor">The HSL color to convert.</param>
    /// <returns>An RGB color object equivalent to the HSL color object passed in.</returns>
    static Color HlsToRgb(HlsColor hlsColor)
    {
        // Initialize result
        var rgbColor = new Color();

        /* If S = 0, that means we are dealing with a shade 
         * of gray. So, we set R, G, and B to L and exit. */

        // Special case: Gray
        if (hlsColor.S == 0)
        {
            rgbColor.R = (byte)(hlsColor.L  * 255);
            rgbColor.G = (byte)(hlsColor.L * 255);
            rgbColor.B = (byte)(hlsColor.L * 255);
            rgbColor.A = (byte)(hlsColor.A * 255);
            return rgbColor;
        }

        double t1;
        if (hlsColor.L < 0.5)
        {
            t1 = hlsColor.L*(1.0 + hlsColor.S);
        }
        else
        {
            t1 = hlsColor.L + hlsColor.S - (hlsColor.L * hlsColor.S);
        }

        var t2 = 2.0*hlsColor.L - t1;

        // Convert H from degrees to a percentage
        var h = hlsColor.H / 360;

        // Set colors as percentage values
        var tR = h + (1.0/3.0);
        var r = SetColor(t1, t2, tR);

        var tG = h;
        var g = SetColor(t1, t2, tG);

        var tB = h - (1.0 / 3.0);
        var b = SetColor(t1, t2, tB);

        // Assign colors to Color object
        rgbColor.R = (byte)(r * 255);
        rgbColor.G = (byte)(g * 255);
        rgbColor.B = (byte)(b * 255);
        rgbColor.A = (byte)(hlsColor.A * 255);

        // Set return value
        return rgbColor;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used by the HSL-to-RGB converter.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="t1">A temporary variable.</param>
    /// <param name="t2">A temporary variable.</param>
    /// <param name="t3">A temporary variable.</param>
    /// <returns>An RGB color value, in decimal format.</returns>
    private static double SetColor(double t1, double t2, double t3)
    {
        if (t3 < 0) t3 += 1.0;
        if (t3 > 1) t3 -= 1.0;

        double color;
        if (6.0 * t3 < 1)
        {
            color = t2 + (t1 - t2) * 6.0 * t3;
        }
        else if(2.0 * t3 < 1)
        {
            color = t1;
        }
        else if(3.0*t3 < 2)
        {
            color = t2 + (t1 - t2) * ((2.0/3.0) - t3) * 6.0;
        }
        else
        {
            color = t2;
        }

        // Set return value
        return color;
    }
```